# ProxyProvider2 in Riverpod (the provider must be created on startup)

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am using the game template of Flutter casual game.

> *Flutter casual game template*: [Link](https://github.dev/flutter/samples/tree/main/game_template)

They are using a provider actually. They have this:

```
  ProxyProvider2<SettingsController, ValueNotifier<AppLifecycleState>,
              AudioController>(
            // Ensures that the AudioController is created on startup,
            // and not "only when it's needed", as is default behavior.
            // This way, music starts immediately.
            lazy: false,
            create: (context) => AudioController()..initialize(),
            update: (context, settings, lifecycleNotifier, audio) {
              if (audio == null) throw ArgumentError.notNull();
              audio.attachSettings(settings);
              audio.attachLifecycleNotifier(lifecycleNotifier);
              return audio;
            },
            dispose: (context, audio) => audio.dispose(),
          ),
```

As you can see in the comment of code, it says

> `Ensures that the AudioController is Created on startup',

and the ProxyProvider has the dispose parameter and it already pass the audio.dispose()

Therefore, I actually convert this into riverpod:

```
/// The AudioControllerProvider is used to control the audio of the game.
final audioControllerProvider = Provider.autoDispose<AudioController>((ref) {
  // final appLifeCycle = ref.watch(appLifeCycleStateProvider);

  final audioController = AudioController();
  audioController.initialize();

  final settingsController = ref.watch(settingsControllerProvider);
  final appLifeCycle = ref.watch(appLifecycleStateProvider);

  audioController.attachSettings(settingsController);

  audioController.attachLifecycleNotifier(appLifeCycle);

  ref.onDispose(audioController.dispose);

  return audioController;
});
```

If we are trying to observe, as you what can see, the provider is auto dispose, and I called the

> ref.onDispose()

since the old one has the dispose parameter.

Then since this audio controller must be created on start up. This is what I did, by creating a ProviderContainer before the runApp() function

```
  // Run Some Riverpod Providers during startup
  final container = ProviderContainer();

  container.read(audioControllerProvider);

  runApp(
    UncontrolledProviderScope(
      container: container,
      child: MyApp(
        adsController: adsController,
        gamesServicesController: gamesServicesController,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

So what actually the problems there?
It actually working fine at all, the problem there is the dispose. As you can see the audiocontroller was called on startup. But when I go to the new screen by calling this function

```
  GoRouter.of(context).push(
                '/game/${questGame[index].gameCategory.gameCategoryKey}');
          }),
```

Then the audio controller it will triggered the dispose. I think the audio controller auto dispose must be not triggered since the provider was called in the main method, right?

Comment: No the fact that the provider gets disposed is logical. If you don't want it to get disposed, don't use autoDispose :)

Comment: in short, it should be manually dispose by using the invalidate function in Ref right?